# How to save data from parse to local data

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm a beginer in Android.
I have small problem in my project , i wanna save my data in parse to local data, but i don't know how to do:
I loaded data from BUS_STOP in parse to my BusStop arraylist.
I added `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());`  to my Application.
This is my code download data to busstops:

```
busStops = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("BUS_STOP");
        query.orderByAscending("stop_id");
        query.setLimit(2000);
        listA = query.find();
        for (ParseObject mBusStop : listA) {
            BusStop newBusStop = new BusStop();
            newBusStop.setName((String) mBusStop.get("name"));
            newBusStop.setStreet((String) mBusStop.get("street"));
            newBusStop.setStyle((String) mBusStop.get("Type"));
            newBusStop.setNext_id((int) mBusStop.get("next_id"));
            newBusStop.setBus_id((int) mBusStop.get("bus_id"));
            newBusStop.setStop_id((int) mBusStop.get("stop_id"));
            double x, y;
            x = (double) mBusStop.get("coor_x");
            y = (double) mBusStop.get("coor_y");
            LatLng a = new LatLng(x, y);
            newBusStop.setLatLngBus(a);
            busStops.add(newBusStop);
        }
    } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and this is my class BusStop

```
@ParseClassName("BUS_STOP")
public class BusStop extends ParseObject{
String name;
String street;
String style;
LatLng latLngBus;
int bus_id;
int next_id;
int stop_id;

public String getPName(){
    return getString("name");
}
public void setPName(String name) {
    put("name", name);
}

public String getPStreet(){
    return getString("street");
}
public void setPStreet(String street) {
    put("street", street);
}

public String getPStyle(){
    return getString("Type");
}

public void setPStyle(String type) {
    put("Type", type);
}

public double getMCoor_x(){
    return getDouble("coor_x");
}

public void setMCoor_x(double coor_x) {
    put("coor_x", coor_x);
}

public double getMCoor_y(){
    return getDouble("coor_y");
}

public void setMCoor_y(double coor_y) {
    put("coor_y", coor_y);
}

public int getMBus_id(){
    return getInt("bus_id");
}

public void setMCoor_y(int bus_id) {
    put("bus_id", bus_id);
}

public int getMNext_id(){
    return getInt("next_id");
}

public void setMNext_id(int next_id) {
    put("next_id", next_id);
}

public int getMStop_id(){
    return getInt("stop_id");
}

public void setMStop_id(int stop_id) {
    put("stop_id", stop_id);
}

public int getStop_id() {
    return stop_id;
}
public void setStop_id(int stop_id) {
    this.stop_id = stop_id;
}

public int getNext_id() {
    return next_id;
}

public void setNext_id(int next_id) {
    this.next_id = next_id;
}

public int getBus_id() {
    return bus_id;
}

public void setBus_id(int bus_id) {
    this.bus_id = bus_id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getStyle() {
    return style;
}

public void setStyle(String style) {
    this.style = style;
}


public LatLng getLatLngBus() {
    return latLngBus;
}

public void setLatLngBus(LatLng latLngBus) {
    this.latLngBus = latLngBus;
}
}
```

If my way is the bad way, tell me the great way please !

Comment: Wait, is your code working or not?

Comment: yeah it working but only load data online ... when i open my app delay 2s for load data

Comment: You'll have to load that data on a background thread, using `Service`, `AsyncTask`, a worker `Thread` or something like that.

Comment: do you have sample tutorial code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've understood from your code and question, you're locking your main thread (the UI Thread) when you load and parse your data.

The main thread is responsible to handle user input and all the screen drawing. So if one operation is taking too long, your app will be frozen until it finishes, and for the user it'll seems like your app crashed.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWwMA-sdOgk) from Udacity explains it very well.

[image]

You can read more about `Thread` on Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).

And [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) shows you how to run things on the background.

---

**EDIT:** Sample code for `AsyncTask`. Taken from the [Android dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

`AsyncTask` allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user interface. It performs the blocking operations in a worker thread and then publishes the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to handle threads and/or handlers yourself.

To use it, you must subclass `AsyncTask` and implement the `doInBackground()` callback method, which runs in a pool of background threads. To update your UI, you should implement `onPostExecute()`, which delivers the result from `doInBackground()` and runs in the UI thread, so you can safely update your UI. You can then run the task by calling `execute()` from the UI thread.

For example, you can implement the previous example using `AsyncTask` this way:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
      * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    }

    /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
      * the result from doInBackground() */
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Now the UI is safe and the code is simpler, because it separates the work into the part that should be done on a worker thread and the part that should be done on the UI thread.

You should read the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) reference for a full understanding on how to use this class, but here is a quick overview of how it works:

- You can specify the type of the parameters, the progress values, and
  the final value of the task, using generics
- The method `doInBackground()` executes automatically on a worker thread
- `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()`, and `onProgressUpdate()` are all
  invoked on the UI thread
- The value returned by `doInBackground()` is sent to `onPostExecute()`
- You can call `publishProgress()` at anytime in `doInBackground()` to
  execute `onProgressUpdate()` on the UI thread
- You can cancel the task at any time, from any thread

> **Caution**: Another problem you might encounter when using a worker thread is unexpected restarts in your activity due to a runtime
>   configuration change (such as when the user changes the screen
>   orientation), which may destroy your worker thread. To see how you can
>   persist your task during one of these restarts and how to properly
>   cancel the task when the activity is destroyed, see the source code
>   for the Shelves sample application.